# How to download File and prompt installation of apk

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-install-apk

I've been struggling to get my application to update from a direct url, i want to download a apk and then prompt to user to install the apk.
How can I do this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/download/" + "WhatsApp Messenger_v2.17.395_apkpure.com.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);


            Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Open APK"));
```

With the code above , opens the app and asks to install with android 4.4, but in my phone android 7.0 doesnt work, gives this alert:"There was a problem parsing the package".

Comment: Why u're struggling if Android does everything by itself when opening apk, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: I am using xamarins forms, i cant even start to download the apk.

Comment: Do you work with signed apk?

Comment: Yes the apk to install is signed,

Comment: There are many ways to down a file, here is one using Android's `DownloadManager` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47064553/4984832

Comment: Then how can i open the apk after is downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

> Then how can i open the apk after is downloaded?

You could use following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
StartActivity(intent);
```

For more information, you could refer to : [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Comment: Gives a exception:
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown

Comment: I edited my post with a code that works in android 4.4 ,  but in android 7.0 doesnt work.

Comment: Is not a error, is a alert, is this only: "There was a problem parsing the package""

Comment: @Phill, you could refer to : http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/